# Musical Chemistry

Tags: visual, rebus

Here I come, with another Rebus.
This is rather easy.

[image]

Hint

> Almost Everywhere, but We Don't Care.

Comment: ...I Care, usually :(

Comment: NB it doesn't work in a British accent.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I assume you're referring to the fourth item? It doesn't work with an American accent either.

Comment: @question_asker, the second, third, and fourth items.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Same. Though the second and third items aren't words in the same way the fourth is - we're only basing our pronunciation of those on the way we pronounce the full word. If I saw those on their own, I would definitely say them in a way that worked with this puzzle.

Comment: @question_asker, the only way I'd pronounce them in a way which works with this puzzle is if, from context, I thought they were in Spanish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it should be

> **HTTP://** (H Ti Ti Pi Wall-Socket-What-Looks-Like-A-Colon Slash Slash)

Comment: As expected, it came so fast that I can't approve it yet. You're right. :)

Comment: @manshu count the doodads

Comment: but the number of electrons in the third shell are always 8

Comment: @question_asker the power outlet represents the `:` I think. Because of the 2 holes.

Comment: As for the "I don't know what that thing is". It's a wall socket. I know that in the US they look different but where I'm from (Netherlands) they look like that and also in a lot of other countries

Comment: @Marius Yeah, I just didn't know if it was supposed to be a "pun" like the elements were

Comment: @IvoBeckers I know, see my above comment

Comment: @IvoBeckers [Here](https://removeandreplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/electrical-plug-and-outlet-type-chart.jpg) Type C